# Migrate to AndroidX cause blow everything

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Let me start from the beginning. I added the latest parse library into my project (parse is the library for handling push notification). after that, I had to upgrade my build tools version from `27.0.3` into `28.0.3`. So as you know in android API 28, `appcompat` not support anymore and I had to migrate into AndroidX.

I did this migration by going into the Refactor menu of Android Studio and select option for `Migrate to AndroidX`.

The confusion is here. my project does build successful and also my app run on the device without a problem but in my code, I already have too many errors. for example in my `MainActivity` the `onStart` method highlighted with red color or static values from `Intent` class is not defined. like `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and many many errors like these.

How can I get rid of these fake errors?

good to know that:

- The clean and rebuild not worked for me.
- The invalidate cache and restart Android Studio not worked for me.
- Installing the latest Google Play Services from SDK Manager not worked for me.

Comment: Are you using android studio 3.2? if yes then i have the same problem after upgrading android studio to 3.2 that gives me fake errors anywhere. so don't worry you are not alone.

Comment: show build.gradle file, gradle.properties and activity imports.

Comment: @android first thank you for sympathy, but these fake errors make me crazy. I can't see my code with too many red lines and in the future, I couldn't recognize which error is valid or not.

Comment: @HussnainHaidar I add files into my question.

Comment: These are really old libraries in build.gradle file upgrade them. Then try invalidate cache.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these two properties are there in gradle.properties file:

> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: Thank you for the response, but already I had these two lines in gradle.properties file. In fact, when I migrate into AndroidX by Android Studio menu. these two lines automatically added into my code.

Comment: then show us your gradle.build file and imports of your activity.